# How do you trim videos in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, virtualdub

I am trying to trim my videos in Virtualdub but I also wanted to make a stream copy of the same video that I am trimming. Unfortunately, Virtualdub does not always give me the results I want as it is always a few seconds off and I cannot stream copy the video as it does not always support the codecs that my video has. I hope that FFMPEG can do the job for me, but I do not know how to trim and cut in FFMPEG. How do you cut and trim in FFMPEG?

Answer (score 3):

ffmpeg parameters

- -ss specifies the start time i.e. the 30th second of stream as 00:00:30
- -t specifies the duration i.e. 10 second stream as 10
- -to specifies the end time i.e. the 90th second of stream as 00:01:30

Note: Only -t will take effect if both  -t and -to parameters are used.

Example script:

`ffmpeg -i canada.mp4 -ss 00:00:30 -to 00:01:30 -c copy oneMinute.mp4`

Comment: Can you post an example of that script?

Comment: ffmpeg -i canada.mp4 -ss 00:00:30 -to 00:01:30 -c copy oneMinute.mp4 and the result of ffprobe -i oneMinute.mp4 is Duration: 00:00:59.73, start: 0.333008, bitrate: 17036 kb/s

Comment: So, it looks it need to learn how to use FFProbe and FFPlay. Thanks for the help.